# Pandas - Filtering out data by weekday

Tags: pandas

I have a Dataframe that has list of dates with sales count for each of the days as shown below:

```
date,count
11/1/2018,345
11/2/2018,100
11/5/2018,432
11/7/2018,500
11/11/2018,555
11/17/2018,754
```

I am trying to check of all the sales that were done how many were done on a weekday. To pull all week-days in November I am doing the below:

```
weekday = pd.DataFrame(pd.bdate_range('2018-11-01', '2018-11-30'))
```

Now I am trying to compare dates in df with value in weekday as below:

```
df_final = df[df['date'].isin(weekday)]
```

But the above returns no rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should remove pd.DataFrame when create the weekday, since when we using `Series` and `DataFrame` with `isin` means we not only match the `values` but also the `index` and `columns` , since the original `index` and `columns` may different from the new created dataframe weekday, that is why return the `False`

```
df.date=pd.to_datetime(df.date)
weekday = pd.bdate_range('2018-11-01', '2018-11-30')
df_final = df[df['date'].isin(weekday)]
df_final
Out[39]: 
        date  count
0 2018-11-01    345
1 2018-11-02    100
2 2018-11-05    432
3 2018-11-07    500
```

---

Simple example address the issue I mentioned above

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,4,5]})
newdf=pd.DataFrame({'B':[2,3]})
df.isin(newdf)
Out[43]: 
       A
0  False
1  False
2  False
3  False
4  False
df.isin(newdf.B.tolist())
Out[44]: 
       A
0  False
1   True
2   True
3  False
4  False
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a `DatetimeIndex` and let `pandas` do the work for you as follows:

```
# generate some sample sales data for the month of November
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'count': np.random.randint(0, 900, 30)}, 
    index=pd.date_range('2018-11-01', '2018-11-30', name='date')
)

# resample by business day and call `.asfreq()` on the resulting groupby-like object to get your desired filtering
df.resample(rule='B').asfreq()
```

Other values for the resampling `rule` can be found [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#offset-aliases)